# First Python class. Using Zybooks

Tags: python

I've decided to learn Python.  I am currently stuck on this example:
**Read two numbers from user input. Then, print the sum of those numbers.
Hint -- Copy/paste the following code, then just type code where the questions marks are to finish the code.

```
num1 = int(input(x)) num2 = ? print(num1 + ?)**
```

I've successfully gotten this 1/2 right. (5 + 10 = 15)  I can't manipulate it to get the additional (6 + 3 = 9).

Comment: Can you post the code that you currently have and a screenshot of the problem? I understand the question posed, but there are many ways to solve it. Seeing a screenshot will help narrow down the options in case they want you to solve it in a specific way.

To post your code here using markdown, you can use ``` before and after your code.

Comment: I don't know how you got one to work but not the other. Post the code you wrote, that's what needs to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is asking you to take in two numbers from the user and then print the sum. You've already got the first number which will be stored in the variable `num1`:

```py
num1 = int(input(x))
```

Now you will need to get a second number as input and print out the sum of both. You could do something like this:

```py
x = "Enter the first number: "
y = "Enter the second number: "
num1 = int(input(x)) 
num2 = int(input(y))

print(num1 + num2)
```

Note that the `x` and `y` variables are just strings that get printed before the input and displayed to the user.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply.  I solved it.  I was putting actual integers in the ()).  The program just wanted int(input()) + int(input()) and run tests itself.  I feel a little silly not realizing how simple the task was.  Thank you.